# System defined list of countries?

Tags: linux, country-codes, countries

Similar to how it works for time zones, is there a system defined way of listing out countries? something which is periodically updated to keep up with the times?

I need to generate a list:

```
ISO 3166-2 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)
Country name (in English)
```

Answer (score 1):

on debian-based you can use what is stored in the : 
`/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`
where all the supported locales are defined

Comment: just got: 
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 12288 Oct 25  2010 charmaps
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 12288 Oct 25  2010 locales
 in Centos in i18n folder

Comment: in the /usr/share/i18n/locales/ you will find all the supported locales (in many files instead of only one)

Comment: not sure how i should interpret those files...! :) File: vi_VN one has territory  "Vietnam". Should i extract those values from all these files?

Comment: soome seem to be country proper names , some are abbreviations

Comment: the territory item seems to be what you're looking for, it is the english name of the country :) For the abbreviate ones it is a problem....

Comment: also see e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html